# tensorflow, high gpu utilization but low training speed

Tags: tensorflow

I got problems while training cnn model on text examples.

1. When training on single GPU, I got very high GPU utilization of approximate 97%, but the training speed is pretty slow. 1000 batches take 450s (64 examples per batch), thus 7ms for each example. On contrast, hierarchical lstm takes only 2~3ms for each example.
2. I tried to deploy my training progress on GPU clusters, but got a weird GPU utilization. I used 4 GPUs and the utilization was 0% for most period. I have tried to modify batch size from 64 to 2, then GPU utilization turned to be normal, but small batch size will lead to low performance. So I want to ask is there a valid way to speedup training progress by using of GPU clusters.

(BTW, these issues only occur when the single input example is very large, e.g. the body content of the news which contains thousands of words. When the input are news titles, GPU clusters works fine)

Is input of format [ 64 (examples/batch) * 2500 (words/example) * 200 (embedding dim) ] too large for my 5-layer cnn model to properly trained?

1.Model definition (adapted from https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class TextCNN(object):
    """
    A CNN for text classification.
    Uses an embedding layer, followed by a convolutional, max-pooling and softmax layer.
    """

    # sequence_length : 2500 (words per doc)
    # num_classes : 36
    # vocab_size : 500,000
    # embedding size : 200
    # filter_sizes : [25, 50, 100]
    # num_filters : [32, 64, 128]
    def __init__(
      self, sequence_length, num_classes, vocab_size,
      embedding_size, filter_sizes, num_filters, l2_reg_lambda=0.0):

        # Placeholders for input, output and dropout
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x")
        self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes], name="input_y")
        self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

        # Keeping track of l2 regularization loss (optional)
        l2_loss = tf.constant(0.0)

        # Embedding layer
        self.W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
            name="W")
        self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
        self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)

        # Create a convolution + maxpool layer for each filter size
        pooled_outputs = []


        def conv2d(x, W, stride_h, stride_w):
            return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,stride_h,stride_w,1], padding="VALID")

        def max_pool(x, h, w):
            return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,h,w,1], strides=[1,h,w,1], padding="VALID")

        def weight_variable(shape):
            initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
            return tf.Variable(initial)

        def bias_variable(shape):
            initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
            return tf.Variable(initial)

        n_conv1 = num_filters[0]    # 32
        n_conv2 = num_filters[1]    # 64
        n_conv3 = num_filters[2]    # 128
        n_fc1 = 200
        n_fc2 = 200

        # filter_sizes : [25, 50, 100]
        for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
            with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
                # Convolution Layer
                print '######## conv-maxpool-%s ########', filter_size
                w_conv1 = weight_variable([filter_size, 40, 1, n_conv1])
                b_conv1 = bias_variable([n_conv1])
                f_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(self.embedded_chars_expanded, w_conv1, 25, 5) + b_conv1)
                print 'conv1: ', f_conv1
                f_pool1 = max_pool(f_conv1, 2, 2)
                print 'pool1: ', f_pool1

                w_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, n_conv1, n_conv2])
                b_conv2 = bias_variable([n_conv2])
                f_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(f_pool1, w_conv2, 2, 1) + b_conv2)
                print 'conv2: ', f_conv2
                f_pool2 = max_pool(f_conv2, 2, 2)
                print 'pool2: ', f_pool2

                w_conv3 = weight_variable([2, 2, n_conv2, n_conv3])
                b_conv3 = bias_variable([n_conv3])
                f_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(f_pool2, w_conv3, 1, 1) + b_conv3)
                print 'conv3: ', f_conv3
                f_pool3 = max_pool(f_conv3, 2, 2)
                print 'pool3: ', f_pool3

                f_size_conv3 = 5 * 3
                f_pool3_flat = tf.reshape(f_pool3, [-1, f_size_conv3 * n_conv3])

                w_fc1 = weight_variable([f_size_conv3 * n_conv3, n_fc1])
                b_fc1 = bias_variable([n_fc1])
                f_fc1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(f_pool3_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)
                print 'f_fc1: ', f_fc1
                pooled_outputs.append(f_fc1)

        i_fc2 = tf.concat(pooled_outputs, 1)
        print i_fc2
        w_fc2 = weight_variable([n_fc1*len(filter_sizes), n_fc2])
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([n_fc2])
        f_fc2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(i_fc2, w_fc2) + b_fc2)
        print 'f_fc2: ', f_fc2
        # Combine all the pooled features
        num_filters_total = n_fc2
        self.h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(f_fc2, [-1, num_filters_total])

        # Add dropout
        with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
            self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, self.dropout_keep_prob)

        # Final (unnormalized) scores and predictions
        with tf.name_scope("output"):
            W = tf.get_variable(
                "W",
                shape=[num_filters_total, num_classes],
                initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")
            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
            l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
            self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
            self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

        # CalculateMean cross-entropy loss
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores+1e-10, labels=self.input_y)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + l2_reg_lambda * l2_loss

        # Accuracy
        with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
            self.correct_predition = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
            self.correct_num = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(self.correct_predition, tf.float32))
            self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self.correct_predition, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

2.Training progress (single GPU)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import datetime
import data_loader_cnn as data_loader
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

import sys
sys.path.append('./model_def')
from cnn_model import TextCNN

# Data loading params
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("train_path", "/data/train_data.idx", "Data source for the positive data.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("valid_path", "/data/valid_data.idx", "Data source for the validation data.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("ckpt_dir", "runs-cnn", "Directory for checkpoints.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("class_num", 36, "Number of total classes")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("vocab_size", 500000, "Number of total distinct words")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("document_length", 50, "Max number of sentences in single text")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("sentence_length", 50, "Max number of words in single sentence")

# Model Hyperparameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("embedding_dim", 200, "Dimensionality of character embedding (default: 128)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("filter_sizes", "25,50,100", "Comma-separated filter sizes (default: '3,4,5')")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("num_filters", "32,64,128", "Number of filters per filter size (default: 128)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("dropout_keep_prob", 0.5, "Dropout keep probability (default: 0.5)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("l2_reg_lambda", 0.0, "L2 regularization lambda (default: 0.0)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("lr", 0.1, "Learning rate (default: 0.1)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("lr_decay", 0.5, "Learning rate decay per epoch (default: 0.6)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("max_decay_epoch", 10, "Max epoch before decay lr (default: 30)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_grad_norm', 5, 'max_grad_norm')

# Training parameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 64, "Batch Size (default: 64)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("num_epochs", 60, "Number of training epochs (default: 200)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("evaluate_every", 1000, "Evaluate model on dev set after this many steps (default: 100)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("checkpoint_every", 50000, "Save model after this many steps (default: 100)")

# Misc Parameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("allow_growth", True, "Allow memory softly growth")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("allow_soft_placement", True, "Allow device soft device placement")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("log_device_placement", False, "Log placement of ops on devices")

# For distributed
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                       "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                       "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("issync", 0, "1 for sync and 0 for async")

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS._parse_flags()
print("\nParameters:")
for attr, value in sorted(FLAGS.__flags.items()):
    print("{}={}".format(attr.upper(), value))
print("")


# Training
# ==================================================
def main(_):
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
        gpu_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=FLAGS.allow_soft_placement)
        gpu_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = FLAGS.allow_growth
        with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session(config=gpu_config) as sess:
            # Load data
            print("Loading data...")
            document_length = FLAGS.document_length
            sentence_length = FLAGS.sentence_length
            train_data = data_loader.load_data(FLAGS.train_path, document_length, sentence_length, FLAGS.class_num)
            valid_data = data_loader.load_data(FLAGS.valid_path, document_length, sentence_length, FLAGS.class_num)
            batch_num_per_epoch = len(train_data[0]) / FLAGS.batch_size

            print 'len train data', len(train_data[0])
            print 'batch_num_per_epoch', batch_num_per_epoch

            # Building model
            cnn = TextCNN(
                sequence_length=document_length*sentence_length,
                num_classes=FLAGS.class_num,
                vocab_size=FLAGS.vocab_size,
                embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_dim,
                filter_sizes=list(map(int, FLAGS.filter_sizes.split(","))),
                num_filters=list(map(int, FLAGS.num_filters.split(","))),
                l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)

            # Define Training procedure
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
            lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
            new_lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[], name="new_learning_rate")
            _lr_update = tf.assign(lr, new_lr)

            tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
            grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cnn.loss, tvars),
                                          FLAGS.max_grad_norm)
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
            grads_and_vars = zip(grads, tvars)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
            train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)

            # Output directory for models and summaries
            timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
            out_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, FLAGS.ckpt_dir, timestamp))
            print("Writing to {}\n".format(out_dir))

            def train_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, epoch_index):
                """
                A single training step
                """

                # hard coding
                if epoch_index < 15:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.1
                if epoch_index >= 15 and epoch_index < 25:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.01
                elif epoch_index >= 25 and epoch_index < 40:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.001
                elif epoch_index >= 40:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.0001

                feed_dict = {
                  cnn.input_x: x_batch,
                  cnn.input_y: y_batch,
                  cnn.dropout_keep_prob: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob,
                  new_lr: new_lr_temp
                }
                current_lr, _, _, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
                    [lr, _lr_update, train_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
                    feed_dict)
                time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                return loss, time_str


            # ====================== dev_step ======================
            def dev_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, writer=None):
                """
                Evaluates model on a dev set
                """
                exp = int(max(epoch_index-FLAGS.max_decay_epoch,0)/20)
                lr_decay = FLAGS.lr_decay ** exp

                feed_dict = {
                  cnn.input_x: x_batch,
                  cnn.input_y: y_batch,
                  cnn.dropout_keep_prob: 1.0,
                  new_lr: FLAGS.lr*lr_decay
                }
                _, loss, correct_num = sess.run(
                    [_lr_update, cnn.loss, cnn.correct_num],
                    feed_dict)
                time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                return len(x_batch), correct_num


            # ====================== eval ======================
            def evaluate(sess, valid_data, batch_size):
                batch_iter = data_loader.batch_iter(valid_data, batch_size)
                example_num = 0
                correct_num = 0
                for valid_x, valid_y in batch_iter:
                    batch_len, batch_corrent = dev_step(sess, valid_x, valid_y)
                    example_num += batch_len
                    correct_num += batch_corrent
                accuracy = float(correct_num) / example_num
                return accuracy


            # Checkpoint directory. Tensorflow assumes this directory already exists so we need to create it
            checkpoint_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(out_dir, "checkpoints"))
            checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "model")
            if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
                os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)
            init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
            saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
            sess.run(init_op)

            # Generate batches
            batch_iter = data_loader.global_batch_iter(
                train_data, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
            # Training loop. For each batch...
            current_step = sess.run(global_step)
            print 'current step', current_step
            while current_step < batch_num_per_epoch * FLAGS.num_epochs:
                current_step = sess.run(global_step)
                epoch_index = current_step / batch_num_per_epoch
                if current_step % batch_num_per_epoch == 0:
                    print("Epoch ", epoch_index)

                x_batch, y_batch = next(batch_iter)
                loss, time_str = train_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, epoch_index)

                if current_step % FLAGS.evaluate_every == 0:
                    accuracy = evaluate(sess, valid_data, FLAGS.batch_size)
                    print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, current_step, loss, accuracy))

                if current_step % FLAGS.checkpoint_every == 0:
                    path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=current_step)
                    print("Saved model checkpoint to {}\n".format(path))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

3.Parallel training progress

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import datetime
import data_loader_cnn as data_loader
from cnn_model import TextCNN
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

# Data loading params
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("train_path", "/data/slice/", "Data source for the positive data.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("valid_path", "/data/valid_data.idx", "Data source for the validation data.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("ckpt_dir", "runs-cnn", "Directory for checkpoints.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("class_num", 36, "Number of total classes")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("vocab_size", 500000, "Number of total distinct words")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("document_length", 50, "Max number of sentences in single text")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("sentence_length", 50, "Max number of words in single sentence")

# Model Hyperparameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("embedding_dim", 200, "Dimensionality of character embedding (default: 128)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("filter_sizes", "25,50,100", "Comma-separated filter sizes (default: '3,4,5')")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("num_filters", "32,64,128", "Number of filters per filter size (default: 128)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("dropout_keep_prob", 0.5, "Dropout keep probability (default: 0.5)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("l2_reg_lambda", 0.0, "L2 regularization lambda (default: 0.0)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("lr", 0.1, "Learning rate (default: 0.1)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("lr_decay", 0.5, "Learning rate decay per epoch (default: 0.6)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("max_decay_epoch", 10, "Max epoch before decay lr (default: 30)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_grad_norm', 5, 'max_grad_norm')

# Training parameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 64, "Batch Size (default: 64)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("num_epochs", 60, "Number of training epochs (default: 200)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("evaluate_every", 1000, "Evaluate model on dev set after this many steps (default: 100)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("checkpoint_every", 50000, "Save model after this many steps (default: 100)")

# Misc Parameters
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("allow_soft_placement", True, "Allow device soft device placement")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("log_device_placement", False, "Log placement of ops on devices")

# For distributed
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                       "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                       "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("issync", 0, "1 for sync and 0 for async")

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS._parse_flags()
print("\nParameters:")
for attr, value in sorted(FLAGS.__flags.items()):
    print("{}={}".format(attr.upper(), value))
print("")


# Training
# ==================================================
def main(_):
    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster,job_name=FLAGS.job_name,task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    issync = FLAGS.issync
    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
                          worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
                          cluster=cluster)):
            # Load data
            print("Loading data...")
            document_length = FLAGS.document_length
            sentence_length = FLAGS.sentence_length
            train_path = FLAGS.train_path + str(FLAGS.task_index)
            train_data = data_loader.load_data(train_path, document_length, sentence_length, FLAGS.class_num)
            valid_data = data_loader.load_data(FLAGS.valid_path, document_length, sentence_length, FLAGS.class_num)
            batch_num_per_epoch = len(train_data[0]) / FLAGS.batch_size

            print 'len train data', len(train_data[0])
            print 'batch_num_per_epoch', batch_num_per_epoch

            # Building model
            cnn = TextCNN(
                sequence_length=document_length*sentence_length,
                num_classes=FLAGS.class_num,
                vocab_size=FLAGS.vocab_size,
                embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_dim,
                filter_sizes=list(map(int, FLAGS.filter_sizes.split(","))),
                num_filters=list(map(int, FLAGS.num_filters.split(","))),
                l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)

            # Define Training procedure
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
            lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
            new_lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[], name="new_learning_rate")
            _lr_update = tf.assign(lr, new_lr)

            tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
            grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cnn.loss, tvars),
                                          FLAGS.max_grad_norm)
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
            grads_and_vars = zip(grads, tvars)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
            train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)

            # Output directory for models and summaries
            timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
            out_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, FLAGS.ckpt_dir, timestamp))
            print("Writing to {}\n".format(out_dir))

            def train_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, epoch_index):
                """
                A single training step
                """

                # hard coding
                if epoch_index < 15:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.1
                if epoch_index >= 15 and epoch_index < 25:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.01
                elif epoch_index >= 25 and epoch_index < 40:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.001
                elif epoch_index >= 40:
                    new_lr_temp = 0.0001

                feed_dict = {
                  cnn.input_x: x_batch,
                  cnn.input_y: y_batch,
                  cnn.dropout_keep_prob: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob,
                  new_lr: new_lr_temp
                }
                current_lr, _, _, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
                    [lr, _lr_update, train_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
                    feed_dict)
                time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                return loss, time_str


            # ====================== dev_step ======================
            def dev_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, writer=None):
                """
                Evaluates model on a dev set
                """
                exp = int(max(epoch_index-FLAGS.max_decay_epoch,0)/20)
                lr_decay = FLAGS.lr_decay ** exp

                feed_dict = {
                  cnn.input_x: x_batch,
                  cnn.input_y: y_batch,
                  cnn.dropout_keep_prob: 1.0,
                  new_lr: FLAGS.lr*lr_decay
                }
                _, loss, correct_num = sess.run(
                    [_lr_update, cnn.loss, cnn.correct_num],
                    feed_dict)
                time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                return len(x_batch), correct_num


            # ====================== eval ======================
            def evaluate(sess, valid_data, batch_size):
                batch_iter = data_loader.batch_iter(valid_data, batch_size)
                example_num = 0
                correct_num = 0
                for valid_x, valid_y in batch_iter:
                    batch_len, batch_corrent = dev_step(sess, valid_x, valid_y)
                    example_num += batch_len
                    correct_num += batch_corrent
                accuracy = float(correct_num) / example_num
                return accuracy


            # Checkpoint directory. Tensorflow assumes this directory already exists so we need to create it
            checkpoint_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(out_dir, "checkpoints"))
            checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "model")
            if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
                os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)
            init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
            saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

            ################################################################
            sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                    logdir=checkpoint_prefix,
                                    init_op=init_op,
                                    summary_op=None,
                                    saver=saver,
                                    global_step=global_step,
                                    save_model_secs=60)

            with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target) as sess:
                # Generate batches
                batch_iter = data_loader.global_batch_iter(
                    train_data, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
                # Training loop. For each batch...
                current_step = sess.run(global_step)
                while current_step < batch_num_per_epoch * FLAGS.num_epochs:
                    current_step = sess.run(global_step)
                    epoch_index = current_step / batch_num_per_epoch
                    if current_step % batch_num_per_epoch == 0:
                        print("Epoch ", epoch_index)

                    x_batch, y_batch = next(batch_iter)
                    loss, time_str = train_step(sess, x_batch, y_batch, epoch_index)

                    if current_step % FLAGS.evaluate_every == 0:
                        accuracy = evaluate(sess, valid_data, FLAGS.batch_size)
                        print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, current_step, loss, accuracy))

                    if current_step % FLAGS.checkpoint_every == 0:
                        path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=current_step)
                        print("Saved model checkpoint to {}\n".format(path))
            sv.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Tensorflow version I use is 1.0.1